# Can someone criticise my incorrect proof about a set being open?

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

In the question I have to decide whether the set $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;x/y\leq 7\}$ is open, closed or neither. I attempted to prove it was closed but it turns out it is neither can someone tell me whats wrong here. 
So let $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;x/y > 7\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;y>0,\;x -7y > 0\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;|\;y<0,\;x -7y < 0\}$

Set $g(x,y)=y$,  $ f(x,y)=x-7g$ then g and f are cts functions. Then

$A=(g^{-1}(0,\infty)\cap f^{-1}(0,\infty))\cup(g^{-1}(-\infty,0)\cap f^{-1}(-\infty,0))$

So A open by cty of f and g so $\mathbb{R}^2$ \ $A=S$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

At the very end of the proof, you said that $\mathbb R^2\setminus A=S$.  You overlooked the fact that points where $y=0$ are in neither $A$ nor $S$, because $x/y$ is undefined there.